# Reproduce 4 sounds in chain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, time, timing, javascript-audio-api

I have an array of Audios that look like this:

```
let pentagram = [
  {
    sound: new Audio('somePathtoAudio.wav')
  },
  {
    sound: new Audio('somePathtoAudio.wav')
  },
  {
    sound: new Audio('somePathtoAudio.wav')
  },
  {
    sound: new Audio('somePathtoAudio.wav')
  }
];
```

And i need to reproduce this 4 audios that reproduces everyone for 1 second one after each other.

```
function play() {
    pentagrama[0].audio.play();
    pentagrama.forEach((part, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        part.audio.pause();
        part.audio.currentTime = 0;
        if (i + 1 < pentagrama.length) pentagrama[i + 1].audio.play();
      }, (i + 1) * 1000);
    });
}
```

This is what i've done and i dont really like it, it works, but is there a better way? 
Because i've been looking for something that looks more elegant and i haven't found that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a better way - using [SoundPlayer.js](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/#soundplayerjs)!

Load [SoundPlayer](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/SoundPlayer.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/SoundPlayer.js"></script>
```

And this will be easy!

```
const player = new SoundPlayer();

function play () {

    player.load( 'sound1.mp3' ).play( 1 );
    player.load( 'sound2.mp3' ).play( 2 );
    player.load( 'sound3.mp3' ).play( 3 );
    player.load( 'sound4.mp3' ).play( 4 );

}
```

Where the number passed to play is seconds until it will be played.

**EDIT**

If you want the sound to only be played for 1 second, use:

```
const player = new SoundPlayer();

function play () {

    player.load( 'sound1.mp3' ).play( 1, 1 );
    player.load( 'sound2.mp3' ).play( 2, 1 );
    player.load( 'sound3.mp3' ).play( 3, 1 );
    player.load( 'sound4.mp3' ).play( 4, 1 );

}
```

Comment: Yeah it solves my wait problem, but I need also to get this audio last only for 1 sec, thanks for your aport

Comment: Edited original answer and added some extra :)

Comment: Glad i could help :)